# Un Comtrade Scraping using Phyton

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am new to using Python for web scraping. I need to extract data from the following URL: https://comtradeplus.un.org/TradeFlow?Frequency=A&Flows=X&CommodityCodes=TOTAL&Partners=0&Reporters=all&period=2023&AggregateBy=none&BreakdownMode=plus

On this page, at the bottom, there is a Download button that by default creates a CSV file and copies it to the Windows download folder. I don't need the entire database; for example, I need a product with code 070110, for the Reporters code of country 688 and Partner code 70. Year should be 2022 and frequency should be month.

This code works but I am getting annual data not by months

import pandas as pd
import requests

api_url = "https://comtradeapi.un.org/public/v1/preview/C/A/HS"

params = {
"freqCode": "M",
"period": "2022",
"reporterCode": "688",
"partnerCode": "70",
"flowCode": "X",
"cmdCode": "070110",
"customsCode": "c00",
"motCode": "0",
"partner2Code": "0",
"undefinednone": "",
"breakdownMode": "plus",
"includeDesc": "True",
"countOnlyFalse": "",
}

data = requests.get(api_url, params=params).json()

df = pd.DataFrame(data["data"])
print(df.head())